# How to loop through a series and create a new series based on values from the original series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series, linspace

I am trying to create a new series that uses entries from a series of two columns.
Each column contains a limit, upper and lower and I want to create an array for each entry of the new series.

Series =

|  | lower | upper |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20.20 | 56.20 |
| 1 | 10.00 | 77.70 |

What I want is to use the following code:

```
np.linsapce(lower,upper,5)
```

this creates an array of 5 points, starting from lower number to upper. The new series would look like:

|  | range |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [20.2, 25.34285714, 30.48571429... 56.2] |
| 1 | [10., 19.67142857, 29.34285714... 77.7] |

Comment: A Series of two columns is actually a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
df['range'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.linspace(x['lower'], x['upper'], 5), axis=1)
```

```
>>> df
   lower   upper                                            range

0    20.2   56.2                   [20.2, 29.2, 38.2, 47.2, 56.2]
1    10.0   77.7  [10.0, 26.925, 43.85, 60.775000000000006, 77.7]
```